# Accidentally cancelled update to 2.3 this morning; how do I get it back?

Tags: updates

I woke up 2 hours ago and there was the message on my phone (HTC DROID Incredible) that a new update was available and that my phone would restart to download and install the update and of course I click the "Install" button, but the way I was holding my phone was odd and my palm accidentally hit the "Cancel" button as it was counting down to restart the phone and it only got down to 5. Now the update seems to have disappeared. When I go into `Settings > About phone > System updates` my phone says that my system is already up to date. I also tried doing that `*#*#CHECKIN#*#*` thing which did not do anything (it said I was checked in but the update didn't come back). I thought the update would have automatically popped back up after 30 minutes but it's been two hours and my phone seems to have no trace that the update was even sent to my phone.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the phone?

Comment: @eldarerathis: Yes, that is the first thing I tried, but I'll try it again just to be sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Others are reporting similar issues](http://www.phonesreview.co.uk/2011/11/15/confusion-of-droid-incredible-android-2-3-gingerbread/).  Is your build number 4.06, 4.08 or other?  I would suspect that if you missed the initial rollout you'll have to wait a bit, since they would want to do it gradually and not overload the network.  You might get prompted again later or they might enable manual upgrades at some point.

[Verizon says you can update over Wi-Fi](http://support.verizonwireless.com/pdf/system_update/incredible_instructions.pdf), though again it looks to be an automatic thing rather than manual, but maybe you'll get a second notification if you connect to Wi-Fi.

Comment: My build number says `3.26.605.1 CL264707 release-keys`. I don't have anything that says 4.06 or 4.08.

Comment: @animuson So you definitely didn't get updated.  I added some info about a possible Wi-Fi upgrade, but I think you'll probably just have to wait unfortunately.

Comment: I always have my Wi-Fi connected while I'm at home. I actually turned it off initially to see if it would re-find the update over 3G with no luck, then turned it back on. I guess I'll just have to wait and see how long it takes to get it again. :(

Comment: Took a long time to make it back to my phone, but it finally popped back up just a few minutes ago. :D I made sure not to hit cancel this time.

Comment: @animuson Glad to hear it :)

Answer (score 2):

You might try doing a [manual update](http://forums.androidcentral.com/verizon-droid-incredible/116534-ota-gingerbread.html#post1222770).

Answer (score -1):

After a week check system upgrade option in settings when u will open the option they will automatically find new system ....their will be writen deceting a new upgrade and if u will get a new upgrade I will get it...it takes 7-14 days or mabe sometimes less....it also happened with me just wait and u will get new one ......be carefull ..